# How to prevent pandas from removing 'NA' character string when reading a csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read in a CSV file that has product data, one of the dataframes contain a product line code 'NA', when I output the data to new file, the Line Code 'NA' is no longer part of the dataframe, it's been removed and is now blank field, how can I stop this from happening?

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\' + filename, sep=',', quotechar='"', encoding='mbcs',
                   low_memory=False)
```

My desired dataframe would look like this:

```
"Line Code"    "Product SKU"
AB              Product1
AB              Product2
AB              Product3 
NA              Product4
NA              Product5
NA              Product6
MV              Product7
MV              Product7
MV              Product7
```

Comment: Could you show how you call `read_csv` ?

Comment: very likely that you call `dropna()` at some point

Comment: I never call dropna().

Comment: what if you use the `na_rep='NA'` in the `to_csv` statement.

Comment: adding na_rep='NA' works but fills all the other blank dataframes with 'NA' also, any way to limit this to specific dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the dataframe with `keep_default_na=False`, possibly specifying with `na_values` the set of values that you want to consider as "genuine" NaNs:

```
# custom admissible NaNs values, 'NA' is not in this list
na_values = ['', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND',
'-1.#QNAN', '-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND',
'1.#QNAN', 'N/A', 'NULL', 'NaN',
'n/a', 'nan', 'null'
]

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\' + filename, 
                    sep=',', 
                    quotechar='"', 
                    encoding='mbcs', 
                    low_memory=False, 
                    na_values = na_values # specify custom NaN values
                    keep_default_na=False) # and use them
```

Here's a reproducible example of what could be happening here:

```
# create dataframe with NA and write it to file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Line Code':['MV', 'RM', 'NA', 'AB'], 
                   'Product SKU':['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4']})

df.to_csv("mydf.csv", index = False)

# read it in, in two different fashions
df_problematic = pd.read_csv("mydf.csv")
df_ok = pd.read_csv("mydf.csv", keep_default_na = False)
```

in `df_problematic`, the 'NA' value is interpreted as NaN, which is not what you want (refer to [the `read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for options when reading csv files in pandas and for info about the default list of symbols interpreted as NaNs).

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared for the improvement of the answer.

Comment: No problem (-: see you around.